# Driving NDepend with NUnit

Tags: nunit, teamcity, build-automation, ndepend, cqlinq

Is it possible to use NUnit to run CQL queries using NDepend?  It would be nice to be able to just include the NDepend dlls in a UnitTests library and write tests like:

```
[Test] public void
DomainAssemblyHasNoDatabaseDependencies
...
```

or something similar.

This would make it very easy to integrate with Team City, and automatically fail the build if any of the static analysis tests fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible thanks to [NDepend.API](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html) released with NDepend v4, and especially thanks to the namespace [NDepend.CodeQuery](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.CodeQuery_namespace.html) that contains what is needed to run programatically CQLinq or CQL code queries and rules presented as a simple string.

[Here is documentation to get started with NDepend.API](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API_gettingstarted.html).

We advise looking at the source code of the PowerTool named *Query Code with CQLinq* available in *$NDependInstallPath$\NDepend.PowerTools.SourceCode\NDepend.PowerTools.sln*

Notice finally, that thanks to NDepend.API, you can also write directly your code queries/rules or even static analyzer with C# or VB.NET code (hence code that can be embedded in your unit tests).

Comment: Did this realise or is it still on the todo list?